# How to handle a software/tool release with a new feature that can answer many (non-duplicate) questions

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

If there's a process for this that's already established in some Meta question, I couldn't find it either through searching or in the "Similar questions" list, but I'd welcome a "Duplicate" pointer if it can answer the question.

There are a sizeable number (upwards of 35 by my count) of questions where the *root cause* (or occasionally an ancillary cause) is the lack of [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) support in [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux).  Now that *might* make it a general-computing issue (and it sometimes is), but there are also a number of questions where:

- The root cause is lack of systemd support
- The question is (IMHO) on-topic (unique to programming, e.g. [installation of code-server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65692974/11810933))
- There are non-systemd solutions available.

But yesterday, Microsoft released a new preview version of WSL that supports systemd.  Pretty much every one of those 35+ questions I have found could be answered with a new answer that says something like:

> With yesterday's preview release of [WSL 0.67.6](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.67.6), it is now possible to run systemd under WSL2.  With this enabled, you should be able to do (x from question) without any other workarounds.
>
> This feature does require Windows 11, so those using WSL on Windows 10 should continue to use the workarounds from the other answer(s) here.

Some of these questions could certainly be closed as off-topic or duplicates.  However, since there's been no activity on them in some time, I can't take them to [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/).  From past history, they are unlikely to get the votes-to-close since WSL is a low-volume tag where close-votes typically expire before action.

I'd love to avoid having 35+ questions updated with (essentially) the same answer somehow, but what's the right way to handle this type of situation?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why _can't_ you just add an an answer like this? I use WSL2 on Windows 10, and I'm stuck with that, but if someone has the option of upgrading to Windows 11 to pick up your solution, why _isn't_ that a valid option you could propose as a solution to the problem at hand? I don't see why it's a problem, or why it needs to be community wiki. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas If it were one question, then I'd have no problem adding the answer -- But it's 35 questions with essentially the same new, valid answer.  Posting the same answer on multiple questions is generally frowned on; hence the suggestion of a community-wiki answer on each of the existing questions.

Comment: Questions aren't duplicates because they have the same answer, they're duplicates if they have the same question. It's not like you're spamming a new library you wrote, you're just posting a potential solution (upgrade to Windows 11, upgrade to WSL 0.67.6). I think the library spam is what's really looked down on more than anything. And for those of us who _can't_ upgrade to Windows 11 ... well there's the rest of the answers.\

Comment: Of course, if the question is explicitly "I'm using Windows 10 with WSL and am having issues doing X", then I don't think that this is an answer there either (just like I don't think "use jquery" is an answer when the question says explicitly "I'm using plain old javascript"). But rolling back around and saying "this is now supported" on a Windows 11 question seems perfectly valid.

Comment: Do the answers to all of these 35 questions boil down to "Use `sudo service SERVICE_NAME ...`" or "Here is a workaround to enable systemd in WSL"?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas ... no, questions *are* duplicates when they have the exact same answer.

Comment: @Gimby No, questions are duplicates when they *only* have the exact same answer(s).  Take, for example, these two non-technical questions - (1) How do I deal with my cat allergy?   (2) How do I deal with my ragweed allergy?  Both questions *can* be answered by a doctor by prescribing the same allergy medication (e.g. Montelukast).  That doesn't make them duplicates, since each also has an answer that is *unique* from the other, (1) get rid of the cat, (1) vacuum more frequently, (2) stay indoors in late summer and fall.

Comment: We shouldn't close questions as duplicates just because *one* answer is the same.  That precludes the other unique answers for each question from being provided.  And in the future, there may be a *better* solution for one, but not the other -- Perhaps a medication that specifically works for cat allergies, or a medication for the cat itself to reduce dander (which is being worked on).  Only close questions when we are *sure* that the *question* is a duplicate, and that unique answers aren't possible to each one.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Good question, but unfortunately not.  If those were the *only* two options (now with the third solution of "upgrade") then I would consider them duplicates.  And I thought I'd find more of those than I did.  But many (if not most) of these questions have unique possible solutions apart from those two (now three) answers, so we shouldn't close them as dupes, IMHO.

Comment: @Gimby No they're not. Trivial example: if I skip a null check in Java and a null check in C# and nil check in Go, they're not duplicates because the answer in all cases is "check for null/nil".

Comment: Perhaps wait until it gets into an actual release rather than just a preview - you never know if there could be a big problem which only becomes evident when a lot of people have tried it that means it has to be delayed to another release.

Comment: @StephenRauch: Why did you mod-delete one of the answers?

Answer (score 10):

Obviously, questions that should be closed as duplicate or for some other reason should be closed accordingly.

That leaves us with a number of questions that don't have the most up-to-date answer on them. We've already agreed these questions shouldn't be closed, which means they deserve an answer, and any user arriving at these questions deserves to see an answer. There's really only three ways that we can convey the updated answer:

1. Write the answer on one of the questions, and mark all other questions as a duplicate of that question.
2. Write the answer as a comment on each question.
3. Write the answer on each question.

With regards to point 1: as mentioned, these **questions** are not necessarily duplicated, even if the answer to them might be the same. It was also commented here that users might be (and many probably are) using an older version for which this updated answer is not useful, so pointing them to a duplicate that isn't actually a duplicate won't help.

For point 2: the comment hint says don't answer questions in the comments. Many users disregard this for one reason or another, but that language is explicit, it shouldn't be confusing to understand why leaving the answer as a comment isn't the correct approach. Yes, I could say more here, but this is sufficient in ruling out using comments to answer the question.

Which leaves point 3, write the answer on each question. Why is this a good option:

1. Each user that arrives at one of these questions deserves to see an answer. You commented that "posting the same answer on multiple questions is generally frowned on". I think the people doing this frowning are wrong. The alternative is that we **know** the answer but are actively witholding it so that we don't look greedy. You could use the community wiki option here, but frankly answering 35 questions is still a lot of work. Reputation is earned when others recognize your valuable contributions. Posting these answers is valuable and frankly I'd have no problem with you getting reputation for being prudent.
2. It really doesn't break any rules: it's not spamming if it's the correct answer. These is literally **no alternative** that actually ensures users get the correct answer when they visit a question.
3. Is this a rampant problem? Are you going to set a bad precedent? No. This isn't a one-off "it's acceptable in this case but not in these other cases" scenario. Per points 1 and 2, this should honestly **always** be done when multiple questions can handle the same answer when the questions aren't duplicates. These's no other way to solve this problem. So even if others decide to follow your lead, that would be a good thing.
4. You can probably find a lot of examples of two questions that aren't duplicates being answered in effectively the same way. The difference is the answerers might be different, and the answers might have been posted months or years apart, but I can't see why that would matter.

The one downside I can think of is that either a mod or a bot with mod powers will flag your answering all of these questions identically as spam. I actually think that it's likely going to be the case if you post 35 identical answers, you will be flagged long before you get to the 35th post, as this seems like a decent albeit naive approach to spam detection. So it ultimately comes down to what the mods think about this, because for the reasons listed above, I don't see why this would be inappropriate behaviour.

Answer (score -5):

I'd recommend waiting for a more organic time to bring it up, rather than trying to shoehorn it into existing answers.

If a question about WSL comes up that could be solved with the new version that supports systemd, then it'd be good to answer that new question in that fashion.

If the answer hashes over older ground, then IMO - answer the *new* question, and close the *old* question as a dupe.

Comment: Not  my downvote, but my concern isn't about trying to shoehorn it into existing *answers* (not sure if that was a typo), but that people are invariably going to provide a variation of that answer to those *existing questions* as they find them.  Is it useful to have multiple versions of the same "this now works in ..." answer on 35+ questions?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a problem. This being a temporary issue that will now be resolved, means there beign duplicate ansewrs will at most be an inconvenience for a short amount of time

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds: No, it's useful to have a single canonical.  This is an approach to create that canonical.  I do want to be careful though in assuming that this is a one-size-fits-all solution, which is why I don't recommend going back in time and putting those into existing answers, but suggesting that if it comes up again, then you can form answer and close those other questions as a dupe.

Comment: @Makoto But then how do we prevent/discourage *others* from going back and adding answers to the old questions (assuming they aren't duplicates, and most aren't)?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds:  Well, that's not the goal here.  The goal would be to create a canonical that can be used to close the questions which are similar.  If someone answers an older question, then that means the canonical couldn't apply, and the system works since someone's answering an older question (which we don't discourage).