# Why was my answer deleted for plagiarism, despite mentioning the source?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, moderation, plagiarism

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38750738/395857) was deleted by a mod for plagiarism. Why? It mentioned the source clearly ("*code from [gns-ank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22787457/395857)*").

Answer:

> Since Matplotlib [isn't able](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1369) to use the metric system natively, if you want to specify the size of your figure in a reasonable unit of length such as centimeters, you can do the following (code from [gns-ank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22787457/395857)):
>
> ```
> def cm2inch(*tupl):
>     inch = 2.54
>     if isinstance(tupl[0], tuple):
>         return tuple(i/inch for i in tupl[0])
>     else:
>         return tuple(i/inch for i in tupl)
> ```
>
> Then you can use:
>
> ```
> plt.figure(figsize=cm2inch(21, 29.7))
> ```

Deletion reason:

> Plagiarised from [Specify figure size in centimeter in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22787457/1839439). [Dharman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman)**♦** [7 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib/38750738?noredirect=1#comment131835652_38750738)

Note: *gns-ank* [is](https://web.archive.org/web/20160831214058/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967348/posting-multipart-form-data-with-flurl) the old username of [aigna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105870/aignas).

Comment: Your content wasn't in a block quote, meaning that the content wasn't properly formatted. If you are quoting someone put it in a blockquote; otherwise it looks the content is your own not someone else's. There's an article in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) that shows the correct way to quote content.

Comment: As far as I can tell, practically the entire content is taken from the other answer. Even the linked issue is the same and the second, unattributed code block only swapped out the numbers (whether that makes it less similar or intentionally obscures the similarity I'll leave up for the readers). While it's not a verbatim copy, I'm having a hard time seeing what content it actually adds.

Comment: Plus, if your answer is the same as someone else's on the site, then I fail to see why the answer is useful. Either close as a duplicate, or if it's the same question you are both answering then write *your own* answer.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, it's two different questions. I'll add the quotes (I hadn't put them to save space and the attribution seemed clear to me).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think the numbers are different because I was using it in my code. I don't think it obscures the copy paste at all... The copied answer is in a different location.

Comment: The question didn't ask "How to change the size of figure in metric?". Why repost an answer from the question which does?

Comment: @gre_gor because in most countries people use metric.

Comment: “it's two different questions.” - But both of those questions are answered by the same answer, which makes them duplicates, so only one of them should be answered. Different metrics for plagiarism, give me a break, plagiarism is plagiarism.

Comment: @SecurityHound "both of those questions are answered by the same answer, which makes them duplicates": I disagree, that doesn't make them duplicate.  "Different metrics for plagiarism, give me a break, plagiarism is plagiarism. "  how is it plagiarism when I clearly mentioned  and linked to the source?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - When you copy the function and copy nearly verbatim the closing statement, that’s what makes it a duplicate, and without a quote and citation plagiarism. Regardless you submitted a duplicate answer instead of flagging the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't feel a quote is necessary if the attribution is clear.  But happy to add it, or the mod could have added it instead of removing the answer. And it definitely doesn't qualify as plagiarism.

Comment: Plagiarism is more than a close/delete reason, it's a serious accusation. Plagiarism means copying someone else's work **and claiming it's your own work**. That didn't happen here, the work was clearly attributed to someone else. It's *not* plagiarism. Arguing whether it should be deleted for other similar reasons is a different discussion.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Still doesn’t change the fact, you should have flagged as a duplicate, instead of submitting your answers. Had you properly cited and quoted the original answer, your answer still should be deleted, in my opinion.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - Certainly

Comment: Related: *[When should answers consisting entirely of cited, copied content be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404102)* and *[Answers entirely copied though properly attributed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404102)*. Though it appears to be only partially in this case.

Comment: AFAIK deletion for "plagiarism" does not constitute any extra punishments, so the discussion should be around what the correct action should be in this case, no? It seems to me that the deleted "answer" should have been a comment on the question with a link to the answer, instead. Whether it was plagiarism or not; it definitely shouldn't be an "answer".

Comment: @Multihunter Like asker commented on an answer: "Comments can be deleted anytime: they aren't viewed as long-lasting content on SE. Also, they shouldn't contain answers."

Comment: @Clockwork that's why flagging the question as a duplicate would have been the correct action, as that comment is directly related to the flag.

Comment: @SecurityHound "...you should have flagged as a duplicate, instead of submitting your answers.." Why? Everyone is free to use their own estimation of whether a question is a duplicate or not. Somebody maybe should have flagged, but not necessarily Franck. And so far the questions are still not duplicates. Once you acknowledge that one answer can answer two different questions we basically run into the problem of either copying answers or leaving them out. Your choice what you prefer, but I know what I prefer.

Comment: @Trilarion - A duplicate is determine if an answer to an existing question, answers another question that is asked, if the author is submitting a literal verbitam copy of an answer from a question that sounds like it should be a duplicate of that existing question.  The alternative is that question that was copied verbatim does not actually answer the new question. What is clear is that the verbitam copy shouldn't have neve been submitted.

Comment: @Clockwork In this case, the question was "how to change figure size", and the "answer" was  "here's how to use cm in the command to change figure size". The only way you can consider this to be a valid answer is if you consider the questions to not be meaningfully different. In which case, they are duplicates. If they are meaningfully different questions, then it seems that linking to a different - but related - answer is the correct thing to do. I feel like the SO interface should encourage this by presenting that linked question in the side-bar.

Comment: There are a lot of non-codified terms here like "does not actually answer" (SecurityHound) or "valid answer" (Multihunter) which hints that there can be answers that do not answer a question. However, this conflicts with the often used interpretation of flagging as "not an answer" only if it really isn't answering any (programming) question at all. Therefore it's not clear what should happen to a "not actually answering/not valid" answer apart from downvoting.

Comment: I don't understand this. Here is [a much worse case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33036773/how-to-enable-pcntl-in-php-while-using-a-framework-like-symfony-2/43157513#comment131706833_43157513).

Comment: It is illogical. If you had done a ***worse*** thing, not quoting, and somebody else had stepped in and added the quoting, then it is suddenly OK?

Answer (score 63):

Your answer did mention the source, but it didn't contain any original content. You have copied someone else's answer and received reputation for something you didn't write.

Let me quote the help section on ["how to reference material written by others"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing):

> Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.

If you found an answer to a question somewhere else, the correct procedure is to close the question as a duplicate. Do not repost the same answer.

The answer was not in line with our attribution guidelines as mentioned above, which constitues plagiarism. However, even if it was your own answer, it's never ok to post the same answer to two questions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what if that exact same answer was a community wiki?

Comment: @Clockwork Nothing different. Close as duplicate of where that community wiki lies.

Comment: @Clockwork But why? It already exists on the site. Why duplicate it?

Comment: @Dharman I was thinking it _might_ help if the question it duplicates has several answers. But yeah, it's not really useful.

Comment: @Clockwork No, please don't ever duplicate answers. Just close as duplicate. It helps to find the right answer and also reward the original author with rep.

Comment: @Dharman but the question is different. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267318/178179

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt This doesn't matter. As long as the answer is the same the question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I was also wondering whether community wiki would change things. If it wouldn't, then the "*received reputation for something you didn't write*" part of this answer doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: *If you found an answer to a question somewhere else, the correct procedure is to close the question as a duplicate.* - not always advisable. Occasionally an answer will be a great answer for two distinct (non duplicate questions). In such cases where the questions are not duplicates, it is not appropriate to to mark the other question as a duplicate.

Comment: @stevec Then the answer should be tailored to each specific question. Two different questions cannot have identical answers.

Comment: @Dharman yes, they can. As a very simple example 2 is the answer to 1 + 1 *and* 5-3.

Comment: @stevec But then you add your own explanation to how you got to the answer or why is it so. That would make it a different answer.

Comment: @Dharman Consider the following: you see an important question with a bunch of answers that are all horror-shows. You keep searching similar but different questions and find an absolute gem which answers a different question, but also happens to answer the original question. It would be a loss for the community not to make mention of it in the original question. I think if explicit mention of the answer's author is made, and it's linked to, then the community gains by having it, the author receives attribution, and everyone wins. Excessive block quotes can be just clutter that add little.

Comment: @stevec But this is exactly why we have an option to close as duplicate. Use that. This links both questions together and helps everyone. Do not repeat the same answer again.

Comment: @Dharman When I say "*different* questions", I don't simply mean two separate questions, I mean questions which are non-duplicates. It does happen from time to time that two non-duplicate questions are best answered by an identical answer. There are occasions where it's valuable to the community for an identical or near identical answer to be repeated on the different question, with attribution of course.

Comment: @stevec But you are still contradicting yourself. Two questions cannot have identical solutions if they are not duplicates. That's exactly what it means for a question to be duplicate: it has the same answers. If the questions are not duplicates then the answers need to be tailored to each question, which makes the answers different.

Comment: It wouldn't even make any difference if you were the author of the answer. We do not allow duplicate answers on multiple questions. There's even an automatic flag for that.

Comment: @Dharman 'What is 1 + 1?' and 'What is 5 - 3?' proves that theory wrong. Those two questions aren't duplicates, yet they have identical answers.

Comment: @stevec Then they should be closed as duplicates. If they have the same answer then the questions are duplicates. Unless you can post two different answers explaining in two different ways how you arrived at the same result.

Comment: @stevec Those are not identical questions and should not have identical answers. "What is `1+1`?" can have an answer that discusses the addition operator and how it applies to two integer literal operands in a particular language whereas "What is `5-3`?" can have an answer that discusses the subtraction operator and how it applies to two integer literal operands in a particular language. Just because the result of the operation is `2` for both does not mean that the description of the solution should be identical for both.

Comment: @stevec - In this case the author of this meta question copied and pasted an existing answer to a question that would have been a duplicate of the question they answered. Your “different question” scenario isn’t applicable.

Comment: @MT0 That are two different answers then: Addition with result of 2 and subtraction with result of 2.

Comment: @SecurityHound perhaps. My point is a general one: that this assumption (that 2 questions are necessarily duplicates if they can be answered by the same answer) does not hold 100% of the time. So "*If you found an answer to a question somewhere else, the correct procedure is to close the question as a duplicate*" is not always the right thing to do.

Comment: @stevec - **In this case it was** evident by the fact the author’s answer cited an existing question (and erroneously and improperly copied the function from an existing answer). You can’t change my mind that the answer we’re talking about wasn’t plagiarism and was improperly quoted, and even if it was properly quoted and cited, the proper action should have been to link the two questions with a duplicate flag. I might only have 2,000 reputation but that’s only because of the toxicity in the community and the fact I stopped submitting answers to SO. I am very active in SE communities.

Comment: @SecurityHound don't take my comments the wrong way. I am being quite pedantic, because the assumption will *occasionally* be wrong (maybe, like, 1% of the time). For a quick rule of thumb, if an answer correctly answers two questions, those questions are probably duplicates, but not always. I'm talking generally, nothing about this specific case. Also, I never looked at your rep, I almost always try to judge ideas, not accounts/people.

Comment: @stevec Questions of the kind "What is 1+1?" or "What is 5-3?" to which "2" is the correct answers *absolutely are duplicates*. That's exactly what duplicate closure is there for: to strip away the superfluous details of incidental examples. If the questions would depend on the specific operators then just "2" is not a sufficient answer either.

Comment: @Dharman I disagree but either way it shouldn't cause my answer to be deleted, since the issue you raise is about question duplicate.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - Plagiarized content should never exist, the answer you submitted, absolutely was plagiarized. You should have flagged the question as a duplicate instead of submitting an answer

Comment: @SecurityHound: It was not plagiarized, it was copied.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It wasn't just copied, it was plagiarised

Comment: @Dharman: If it was correctly attributed (and it was), it can't be plagiarism -- unless you're redefining what the word *plagiarism* means.

Comment: @Dharman [plagiarism explicitly requires one to pass off work **as their own**](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/144939?redirectedFrom=plagiarism), which the OP evidently did not do since they attributed it to someone else. Unless you have a new definition of plagiarism.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk A single code block was attributed. But if you compare the answers the entire content was used.

Comment: @user438383 They still posted it as an answer of their own. They had their name as the author. It's not enough that they mentioned the author's name because there was nothing of their own in this new answer. All content was written by someone else. You cannot repost someone else's answer as your own even if you say their name.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: No one could honestly read his answer and the question he linked to and come to that conclusion. He didn't link to a code block, he linked to an answer.

Comment: @Dharman: He didn't merely "mention the author's name" he linked to the answer which was the source. That's definitely not plagiarism.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk In that case I am no one. The sole reference "(code from gns-ank)" directly in front of a code block clearly speaks to me that the code block – and only that code block – is taken from the linked answer.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: That code block was immediately followed -- followed as in physically contiguous to -- *Then one can issue plt.figure(figsize=cm2inch(12.8, 9.6))*. This was reworded in OPs answer to *Then you can use plt.figure ...*. Calling someone a plagiarist is a very big deal, it's not ok to justify it by claiming that it wasn't 100% clear that the five words at the end weren't part of the previous thing even though they immediately followed it. You should only level such an serious accusation if there no reasonable way an objective person could interpret it as anything but plagiarism

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk For the purposes of how rules are enforced here, it falls under what is handled as plagiarism here... regardless of what definition of plagiarism one might prefer to use.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Just attributing is not sufficient for it not to be plagiary in the context of Stack Overflow. You need to quote the source materials (using a quote block), and the majority of an answer should be written by your, the quotes should only be used for supporting information.

Comment: I'll put my two cents in, there are so many comments it may not be ready.  It is self-evident to me that two different questions can have the same (or very nearly the same) answer without being duplicates.  E.g. referencing a certain DLL could potentially cure two seemingly dissimilar software bugs.  I think people on SO are very quick to label something a duplicate, which really isn't a duplicate, because circumstances can differ.

Comment: @KevinB: That might be true, though I'd love to see a link that demonstrates that this is the working definition, but that is unacceptable. Word have meanings, and this person (who username may very well be his real name) is now accused of plagiarism, a serious accusation.

Comment: Accused of plagiarism, by a flag only about 30 people can actually see if not for this meta post, on a website that holds no authority upon anything such that the "accusation" would have any merit. It's purely curation. Nothing more.

Comment: @KevinB: Still completely unacceptable and wrong.

Comment: Says who? a minority of SO users? Curation is very important to the continued usefulness of this network, regardless of if it ruffles a few feathers here and there.

Comment: @KevinB: "Curation" that involves unsustainable allegations of plagiarism are unethical and unacceptable.

Comment: These aren't unsustainable allegations. copied answers, even when cited, with no original content is considered plagiarism here.

Comment: @KevinB: Now you're just redefining the word *plagiarism* to suit your argument.

Comment: No, that's the label this site provides on these cases. If you would like it to be called something else, raise a meta discussion on the topic.

Comment: @KevinB: Now your argument is circular: it's called plagiarism because that's what Dharman called it.

Comment: I want to make clear that I have nothing against Dharman, he's a great mod who I admire and *almost* always agree with.

Comment: In reference to whether different questions can have same answers and not be duplicates, [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420488/how-to-handle-a-software-tool-release-with-a-new-feature-that-can-answer-many-n) is mainly a discussion due to such questions, asking how to answer them.

Comment: I am only following guidance from https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing I didn't write this guidance. The user in question hasn't been penalized for this either.

Comment: But only the code was copied, not the entire answer(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen But the rest is just a paraphrase of the original answer. The code was copied word for word, and the rest was slightly altered.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk See, I wasn't going to call this plagiarism. And in fact I didn't. But if you insist on moving the goal post ever so slightly, let me be clear: **The entire content was taken from the original answer.** That includes the introduction with the key point that this isn't natively possible and the supporting reference. Every single statement maps directly to a statement made in the original answer. There is literally no original content in that answer. Since I still haven't said it: Yes, I call that plagiarism. Because that is what it is.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk - The problem we face, is the author should have never submitted their answer, and I still maintain the answer wasn’t properly quoted and cited. Answers which are copied and paste verbatim copies of another answer should never be submitted and are not helpful.

Comment: It might or might not be plagiarism.  But as this answer explains, it didn't follow the rules regarding referencing.  In particular, it violated the rule "Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content."  Failing to follow the rules constitutes sufficient reason for deletion, regardless of whether it should be considered plagiarism or not. Perhaps the reason should be edited to remove the word "plagiarism."

Comment: @D.W. - But I raise the question, Why?, it’s only visible to moderators, the author, and 1% of the user base that can see deleted contributions and arguably close to the definition of plagiarism (which I maintain it was in fact plagiarism in my opinion).

Comment: @SecurityHound, If you're asking why the question should be deleted, I've shared a perspective on that in [my full answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421900/781723).  If you're asking why the reason should be edited, I don't have a strong position one way or another about that, and if you have a different position I'm perfectly comfortable with that.  If by "why?" you are asking some other question, then I haven't understood what you are asking.

Comment: @D.W. - I agree the answer should be definitely remain deleted. I am actually asking, why does it matter it was deleted for plagiarism, virtually nobody can see that is the reason.

Comment: Regarding duplicates, please note that the person asking the question might very often think they have problem X, while they actually have problem Y. Then it can be closed as a duplicate to a question asking about problem Y, since the answers will be the same. Also please note that the oldest question is not necessarily the one to pick as "canonical dupe" target. Keep the question with the highest quality question/answers, no matter post age.

Comment: @Dharman This quote actually seems problematic "Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.". What if I am answering and my answer is directly say a quote from official docs of some library. Nothing to add nothing to remove. Just a quote.  Doesn't that kind of thing appear restricted according to above quote? Whereas it shouldn't.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava You should introduce and explain/paraphrase the solution in your own terms, *quote* (using a quote block) the relevant part of the documentation and also *link* that documentation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah of course you link that and quote, but sometimes the quote from that docs is enough, why paraphrase it if it is already clearly written?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Because that is what Stack Overflow requires of you: _"Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own."_ (https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yeah I see but it is weird requirement, why rephrase it if I can just quote. Also you can see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421927/request-for-clarification-about-the-requirements-for-an-answer-to-not-be-conside)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava "... Doesn't that kind of thing appear restricted according to above quote?..." For all these rules the usual applies: Don't follow the wording, follow the ideas in a rule. This rule's purpose is not to make life more difficult for you. It's just that typically content must be adapted when applied to a special problem. What it wants basically is: adapt the content to fit best the problem. If no adaption is needed, don't do any - is a corollary to it.

Answer (score 18):

In my opinion, the answer does not constitute plagiarism.  But it does seem there is a good case that it violates the rules regarding material written by others: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

In particular, those rules state:

> Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.

The deleted answer constitutes primarily of material copied by others.  That is not what we are looking for here on Stack Exchange.  We are looking for answers that consist primarily of new content.  One can include material written by others to support that answer, but if most or all of the answer consists of material written by others, then it is not what we are looking for.

The rules make clear that such answers are likely to be deleted... which is what happened here.

I think this is a case of rules violations, not a case of plagiarism.  I think there is a reasonable case that this answer should not be considered plagiarism.  I think it was a mis-step to leave a deletion reason mentioning the word "plagiarism".  That is a sensitive word and use of that word can easily be taken as an accusation of a severe breach of norms.  I think the appropriate action was to delete this answer for violating the rules regarding material written by others -- which is different than deleting for plagiarism.

So, what should be done at this point? In my opinion, there is no further action that is worth taking.  If you agree with the premise that the answer violates the rules regarding material written by others, then it should remain deleted.  There is no public accusation of plagiarism.  The reason for deletion is not visible to the public.   If there were a public banner marking this answer as plagiarism, then I would recommend that the banner be edited or deleted to avoid a public accusation of plagiarism, and the answer remain deleted for rules violates, but there is no public banner, so that is not relevant.  So, there is no remedy and no action needed, beyond communicating to the mod a suggestion of leaving a different reason in the future.  That's fine.  Mods are insanely busy and aren't perfect and aren't always going to make the perfect decision every time, and we're all learning how to improve.

---

Separately: the rules require that copied material be placed in a blockquote, to make clear which was copied and which was not.  One could debate whether that rule was followed here.  My position is that this rule was not followed but it doesn't matter in this case.

---

Lastly, regarding duplicates: I think this example illustrates that it's hard to write black-and-white rules regarding duplicates.  If both questions had been asked today, I think there might be a reasonable argument for closing "How do I change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?" as too broad, because it doesn't specify clear requirements about what it is trying to achieve (what size does it want?).  But these are existing historical questions with many answer and many views, and we are sometimes a bit more relaxed about applying existing criteria to past questions.  The goal of closure criteria is to help us build a high-quality archive of information, in the format of questions and answers, and so actions have to be judged in that light.

And I don't think copying an answer from one of those questions to the other is the most useful way to support our mission of building a high-quality archive of knowledge -- regardless of whether it is allowed by the rules or not, I don't think it is desirable or advances the broader mission very well.  For instance, I think leaving a comment that links between the two questions would be a more productive and constructive approach.  So when taking an action that isn't well-aligned with the mission of the site, and also arguably violates the rules of the site, don't be surprised if users flag the answer for deletion or if moderators end up deleting the answer.

Comment: "I think leaving a comment that links between the two questions would be a more productive and constructive approach" -> Comments can be deleted anytime: they aren't viewed as long-lasting content on SE. Also, they shouldn't contain answers.

Comment: "don't be surprised if moderators end up taking some action you don't like." -> I was surprised to be accused of plagiarism, despite mentioning the source. Plagiarism is a job killer in my profession, rightfully so.

Comment: Ok, I am willing to use different words than plagiarism in this case. I can remove the comment I left altogether. I didn't mean that Franck committed deliberate plagiarism. I only wanted to indicate that the reason for deletion was the answer wasn't written by Franck. We don't have to classify this as plagiarism.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, I've revised my answer accordingly.  What I was referring to was: don't be surprised if your answer gets deleted, if it isn't well-aligned with the mission of the site and if it plausibly violates the rules of the site.  I can appreciate that you don't want to be accused of plagiarism.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt As far as I know, even in a scientific context, your answer would be considered plagiary, because it doesn't correctly quote and cite the materials, and passes of things written by others as your own. The mere presence of a link to a source is not sufficient when writing scientific papers, you must clearly distinguish between what you sourced elsewhere and your own words/ideas.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that's why you flag the question as a duplicate as it points to the library of existing answers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel "...The mere presence of a link to a source is not sufficient when writing scientific papers..." I'm all for rigorousness myself, but this is basically setting much higher standards than are typical on this platform (which is not a scientific publication). According to the attribution rules, Franck did it right, a link and a name is all that is needed. If you want to know what exactly are his words, make a diff of the linked version and the actual version. Higher standards might be a really good idea, but then we should expect them from everyone at the same time.

Comment: @Trilarion Materials sourced from others should be quoted. Just providing attribution is not sufficient. And the comment your quote was about scientific literature, because Franck earlier said _"Plagiarism is a job killer in my profession"_, so I assume Franck is aware of the rules applied in scientific literature, which are more stringent than Stack Overflow (and the consequences more severe), so assuming that Franck upholds the standards of his profession, he should have been aware that his answer did not meet those standards. Being surprised of accusations of plagiarism is then odd.

Comment: @Trilarion And yes, according to CC-BY-SA rules, attribution is sufficient, but Stack Overflow itself has additional rules and expectations when it comes to writing answers, which means you have to *quote* what you didn't write yourself.

Comment: FWIW, plagiarism is not just copying of words (i.e. verbatim copying) but also ideas, structure or generally content. See e.g. [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plagiarizing) or [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism). Since practically the entire content comes from the source, this very much seems like plagiarism; at the very least it would be nice if the answer would say *why* it is not instead of using many different ways to say *that* it is not.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "... very much seems like plagiarism..." But doesn't plagiarism requires as a precondition that one obscures the origin, which Franck didn't do. How can that be plagiarism then? He never pretended that the code is his. Copying as such is not plagiarism, especially not if its about ideas or structure. Almost nothing people do is really original, it's very often ideas taken from elsewhere.

Comment: @Trilarion The entire content was copied, not just the code. I don't want to speculate on the intentions of Franck (really, I am only keeping this going since people insist this *category* of behaviour cannot be plagiarism) but "code from X" when in fact all content was adapted obscures the origin.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel "...you have to quote what you didn't write yourself.." I'm all for such rules but they should be applied equally and in a practical way. Do you really want to put code blocks into quote blocks for example? Wouldn't it be simply enough to say that the following part is taken from somewhere or that this work is inspired by that other work? It's only a programmer knowledge database here. If we really want to fight plagiarism I feel that here we aim at the wrong guy.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "..."code from X" when in fact all content was adapted obscures the origin..." I don't fully understand that. The answer is little more than code, so I don't understand the distinction between code and all content and how that obscures the origin.

Comment: @Trilarion Still the answer *is* more than code and even that content is lifted from the other source.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ok, I see. Then maybe let me only say that I think we are aiming at the wrong guy here. The amount of scrutiny and even the deletion is much more effort than the effective improvement of the site would warrant.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, code copied from another source must be put in a quote block.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: The policy that any comment can be deleted at any time only makes sense if not actually done to useful comments.  (Although popular questions do somettimes need cleaning). There are some things like linking a related question that aren't appropriate for whole answers on their own, and can't always work well as an edit to an existing answer or the question. In this case maybe there's a spot in the top answer where an edit could link the metric Q&A, otherwise post a comment. Especially if there aren't a ton of comments already under either the question or a high-ranked answer

Comment: @PeterCordes "The policy that any comment can be deleted at any time only makes sense if not actually done to useful comments": useful comments do get removed sometimes, and there's no way to retrieve them unless one is a mod/staff. Also, I believe to have read that comments shouldn't be used for answers.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Yeah, SO moderators make mistakes sometimes :/.  Or when enough people flag a comment as "no longer needed", I think it automatically gets deleted.  I'm not saying to post the whole answer in comments, I'm saying to post *just a link* to an answer.  Like "Related: [Specify figure size in centimeter in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22787457)".  That's the whole point, not duplicating content; if anything about how best to do it in cm changes, it can get updated there in one place.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: SO doesn't have a good mechanism for a hand-curated list of related questions, other than via comments, or linking in answers.  On low-traffic questions (which won't get a lot of comments over the years) I usually use comments instead of editing other people's answers just to add a bullet list of related questions.  I'd never post a whole answer just for links, or to copy/paste the actual content from another answer to a related question.

Comment: @PeterCordes agreed, no good solutions due to the existing SE system (to their defense, it's uncommon that the same answer applies to two different questions). I prefer duplication over the risk of having one's content deleted and irretrievable by non-mod/staff (I don't want to have to go through the SE dump or some mirror such as archive.org).

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't *plagiarism*, it was duplication of content that already exists on SO.  That's also a bad thing, and is usually avoidable, including in this case.  Deletion was appropriate, IMO, but the message chosen was not great.

Separate from actual attribution, you are still earning rep from basically repackaging someone else's answer with minor tweaks.  It's not a big deal for you, already having plenty of rep, but it's not a precedent we want to allow for people to do in general.  If there was a case where an adapted answer had more value than a link, it would be ok.  (But that would probably require more work adapting it, meaning that the user posting it would be more deserving of the rep they got.)

---

The best thing is for that canonical Q&A about sizing figures in Matplotlib to **link to** the Q&A about doing it in centimetres.  So if people want that, they can find it and go there for the current best way.  Answers to that special case only need to be maintained in one place, where a new answer can be added if the library ever does get metric support.  Unlike off-site links, link rot isn't a concern.

#### How to link related questions:

Stack Overflow doesn't have a first-class mechanism for hand-curated lists of related Q&As, so normally this comes down to **a bullet list at the bottom of an existing answer.  Or sometimes the question**, especially for canonical Q&As.  As in [Editing old questions to add links to similar ones](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419863/editing-old-questions-to-add-links-to-similar-ones/419864#419864)

(Not a link-only answer, though; even without the link-rot concern, an answer isn't the right place for just a link or a list of links.  Even if community-wiki.  It's likely going to be buried and hard to find, because what would people be voting on? The curation effort?  And a list of links to related questions wouldn't even be answering the actual question it was posted under.)

---

A comment (under the question, or an appropriate answer) is another good place to add a Related: link, especially on lower-traffic questions where questions won't need to be cleaned up periodically.  (So probably *not* this canonical, although it's better than nothing even then, and maybe someone will add it to their answer.)  It would look like this.

> Related: [Specify figure size in centimeter in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708695/specify-figure-size-in-centimeter-in-matplotlib)

I use https://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper to turn URLs into question titles, making it super easy to copy/paste links into readable comments.  In this case the title is self-explanatory, otherwise you might add some text describing why someone would want to look at it.  (If the question title can be improved, do that).

Depending on how much value there is in making it more visible, you might comment instead of edit only if there isn't a deep comment thread so it will be visible without people having to click "see more".  Otherwise editing a `Related:` `* url` list into a canonical question or an existing answer is good, if it can be done without being too intrusive.

Comments being good for this is less true on high-traffic canonical Q&As because comments tend to be more frequent, leading to them getting nuked periodically whether they're useful or not.  (This is one of the worst features of Stack Overflow, that there's nowhere officially non-ephemeral to add value to an answer other than editing yourself, or more importantly to explain why an answer to a conceptual question is wrong or outdated despite having lots of upvotes.)

In practice useful comments usually don't get deleted; the policy that any comment can be deleted at any time only works if it's not applied randomly, especially on low-traffic questions.  (Although popular questions do sometimes need cleaning as comments build up, and it's understandable but unfortunate that mods don't always have the time to selectively keep highly upvoted comments there.  Much less understandable when they nuke useful comments from obscure low-traffic questions.)

---

Multiple people have argued that if the same answer is appropriate for two questions, they should be closed as duplicates.  Neither direction of dup closing would be appropriate in this case. But **if not for the existence of the metric Q&A, an answer about doing it in `cm` *would* be fully on-topic on the general Q&A.**  (Franck's argument makes a lot of sense, that many parts of the world use metric units by default, so that's not some obscure use-case.)

- *[Specify figure size in centimeter in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708695/specify-figure-size-in-centimeter-in-matplotlib)* is focused on that problem. Since Matplotlib apparently doesn't directly support centimetres, the answers are about extra stuff you need to do, and wouldn't be good for people looking for the basics of how to set plot sizes or use the library at all.
- *[How do I change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib)* is a generic canonical Q&A where the question body just repeats the title, and one of the high-ranked answers (from Ciro) is a whole tutorial with examples.  But it's not about `cm` or metric, so the metric question shouldn't be closed as a duplicate of this or merged.

**Since SO does have a whole Q&A for that special case, of using metric units, the general canonical Q&A should link that, because many people might be looking for that.**

Answer (score -4):

Your answer wasn't plagiarism, which would require you to copy content without giving attribution. However, you have given attribution and in the required format too (name and link to content).

That answers this question, but lurking in the shadow is the question of, if it wasn't plagiarism, what was it then?

You haven't copied the other answer verbatim (except for the code block). I see differences that mean you put some of your own work into it, even though some people might not see much difference there (but there is a non-zero difference).

It's also a somewhat useful answer, indicated by the positive score.

Furthermore, it's two answers to two separate questions (which are not marked as duplicates currently). Even though answers can be equal to different questions, we currently have no viable way to link multiple questions to the same answer. Therefore, we have no choice but to duplicate answers (if they each answer their question) or simply live without that answer. In general, I prefer copied answers over not having answers to each questions.

Your answer does seem to answer the question (somewhat).

I therefore conclude that this is a legit answer and it should be undeleted because it was deleted in mistake.

However: Two almost identical answers suggest that maybe the questions are duplicates of each other (that should be checked first).

Comment: I'd agree with an argument that it doesn't *need* to be labeled as plagiarism, but why shouldn't it be deleted? It is no more useful than a comment with a link.

Comment: @KevinB Comments can be deleted anytime: they aren't viewed as long-lasting content on SE. Also, they shouldn't contain answers.

Comment: "*we currently have no viable way to link multiple questions to the same answer*" Yes, we do. We can close questions as duplicates. That's the whole reason why we have this feature.

Comment: "*I see differences that mean you put some of your own work into it.*" Please enlighten me which part was added in the new answer that wasn't in the old one?

Comment: @Dharman two different questions may share the same answer. The same two different questions may also have different answers. E.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267319/178179  Hence, it makes no sense to close such questions as duplicates.

Comment: @KevinB "why shouldn't it be deleted? It is no more useful" If content is not useful we downvote it. At least that's what I thought. The answer in question had a positive score however. It must be useful to some.

Comment: @Trilarion It's also upvoted where it was originally posted, and then copied from. It doesn't need to exist in both locations.

Comment: @Dharman "Please enlighten me.." Come on. I leave the diff operation on both answers to you. On this level we do not need to argue. To me they are clearly not verbatim copies and it's clear that the asker here put some (minimal but not zero) effort into it.

Comment: I feel like the answer should have been left to the community to decide (i.e., Stack Overflow voting system). Just my two cents though...

Comment: @KevinB "It doesn't need to exist in both locations. " Yes it does if the questions are different. Last time I checked they were not marked as duplicates. In this case the answer (if it's an answer) must exist in both in questions. And it's positively scored. I really think Franck did the right thing here and also according to the rules. Dharman just falsely accused him of plagiarism. We shouldn't just delete answers without good reason. Maybe we should mark the questions as duplicates.

Comment: @Clockwork I realize the diff is different. But there's no original content in the newer answer. Just because they used different words doesn't mean they added something of their own. The whole answer is copied just with minimal stylistic changes to the text.

Comment: @Clockwork "the answer should have been left to the community to decide" We can vote but voting doesn't really decide anything here. What exactly do you imagine?

Comment: @Trilarion What I meant is: to me, it looks like the relevance of the answer should be decided by the voting system instead of flagging and deletion. The same way some answers aren't deleted, because they're valid albeit show little effort for example.

Comment: receiving upvotes over the years isn't a get out of jail free card for cross-posting/copying answers.

Comment: @Clockwork My impression was that deletion is for harmful content (spam, misleading or wrong content, illegal content) and plagiarism would be counted among them. Now if you think that this isn't plagiarism, you would find it probably harder to justify.

Comment: @Trilarion Yeah, I see your point. I forgot that the main subject of debate was that it was considered as plagiarism.

Comment: @KevinB "...for cross-posting/copying answers." We are homing in on the core of the problem. When is it appropriate to copy content and when not? Opinions on that probably differ. I understand what you mean but my opinion is different. I rather have an answer next to every different question even if it means to copy answers because the system doesn't allow me to associate questions and answers in a many to many relationship. In this case I prefer a copy on the answer side. You and Dharman do not seem to prefer that. That's it.

Comment: The core of the problem is actually how some code regarding conversion to metric units answers the question "How do I change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?" It doesn't, it's just a curious and possibly related, helpful detail, but not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Lundin The question itself is rather bad, only a single sentence without much context what exactly the goal was. Consequently there are many answers trying to guess what the OP wanted to achieve. This answer surely tries to answer the question in the commonly used meaning here that everything that looks vaguely related is not subject to deletion. Typically we trust the voters that they get it right. A negative score would be perfectly okay with me. Deletion is in my eyes moderation deciding in place of users. Users should have decided this not moderators and copying is not bad as such.

Comment: @Dharman: Have you looked at the two questions?  Franck's answer was posted on [How do I change the size of figures drawn with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332289), a generic canonical Q&A where the question body just repeats the title, and one of the high-ranked answers (from Ciro) is a whole tutorial with examples.  The duplicate you're proposing is much more specific, [Specify figure size in centimeter in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14708695).  That duplicate closure would not be at all appropriate.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not proposing a duplicate and I haven't voted to close these questions as duplicate. That's not the topic of the discussion here.

Comment: @Dharman: I didn't think you were actually proposing closing, but you did comment *Yes, we do. We can close questions as duplicates. That's the whole reason why we have this feature* as if that's what Franck should have done here instead.  But no, that wouldn't have been a good option, so that argument doesn't make any sense in the context of this case; that's the point I was trying to make.