# How to reference material written by others - clarification

Tags: discussion, support, help-center, plagiarism

I stumbled upon this from help center which seems problematic to me and I would like to clarify if I got it right.

The [page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) says:

> Do not copy **the complete text of sources**; instead, use their words and
> ideas to support your own. In particular, **answers comprised entirely
> of a quote (sourced or not)** will often be deleted since they do not
> contain any original content.

So imagine this situation:

You provide an answer that is taken from official docs of some library (it even could be a language specification like C standard), *however, there isn't really anything to add or remove*.

So this answer while clearly being still useful, would be considered for deletion according to the above quote. Did I get that right?

But maybe I am interpreting it too strictly and maybe adding few words like "hey yeah this is not the way to use function `f`, and here is sentence to back it up" suffices in practice. In that case maybe Help Center can make it clearer.

---

In [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419330/why-was-this-answer-deleted-by-a-mod) question the answer says actually quote only answers can be ok and aren't forbidden - but to me the way it is written in Help center suggests quote only answers will likely be deleted. So I guess I would change the wording there.

Comment: If a literal quote from the documentation, and nothing more than that, answers the question, the question should probably be closed in the first place...

Comment: @Cerbrus What would be the provided reason for close then? Keep in mind some libs have extensive documentation so it may happen someone overlooked an answer there.

Comment: In 99% of questions, you can at least show how the text from the documentation can be applied to the specific situation of the asker.

Comment: @BDL I would not be so sure about 99% estimate. What if there is no situation to apply it to, rather user just encountered say weird behavior. Then you just provide a quote which explains that behavior.

Comment: Even just expanding, briefly, on the subject, is fine. AS a very crude example something like this would be fine. "Per the {linked} documentation: *"Quoted Text"*. As it states, you therefore need to use the function `XYZ` and ensure you pass the value `'abc'` for the parameter named *def*." Just putting you're own TL;DR to summarise is fine, as you're then using the documentation to backup your statement; which also (in this case) is more verbose on the subject should other users wish to read it.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah maybe in that case "Help Center" should also *clarify that like you did*.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava As BDL says above, you can always demonstrate or expand on the solution in the context of the question asked. If a question can be answered by a straight up quote from the documentation, you should downvote for lack of research, maybe post a comment with the links to docs and move on.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel "downvote for lack of research" -> Hm again I would disagree, like I said there are libraries who have huge documentation, and you can't blame always someone for not finding something there.

Comment: To be more specific, the downvote is for a lack of *evidence* of research, @GiorgiMoniava . If the question is simply *"How do I convert the value `'31/12/2020'` to a `date` in T-SQL."* I would suggest that they didn't do any research. If it was *"How do I convert the value `'31/12/2020'` to a `date` in T-SQL. I tried the style code `103` from the documentation, but it didn't work."* that suggests that they *did* research. (Such a question would still likely get downvotes for a lack of [mre], but there is evidence of they at least *searched* the problem.)

Comment: If the documentation is long, then even stating *"I did have a look at {linked documentation}, however, the article was very long, and I didn't really understand where to start reading it."* would evidence research.

Comment: @Larnu Well yeah downvoting is up to the down voter to decide but this question is not about that.

Comment: "What would be the provided reason for close then? Keep in mind some libs have extensive documentation so it may happen someone overlooked an answer there." I'd suggest the generic "Other - add a comment" fill-in-the-blank VTC reason. As Cerbrus stated, if the question is so basic that simply pointing the asker to specific documentation answers the question, then nothing more is needed. Close the question because it's likely not much use to future readers. The asker is then free to improve the question to clarify what/where/why/how the documentation doesn't help them and reopen it.

Comment: If, as you say yourself, _"there isn't really anything to add or remove"_, then just post the reference as a comment instead of an answer. You could even invite the OP to post their own answer if they found that helpful. But as others have already suggested, the situation where there is _absolutely nothing of value_ to be added in an answer beyond quoting a source seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @DrewReese It doesn't have to be a quote from the library docs, could be a quote from the specification (like C standard). In that case you can't expect any beginner to have read say C standard

Comment: What do you want to discuss here? Whether the requirements are literally as they are written or whether they should be changed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah why is the site asking for originality? If like I said quote from specification of some language (which  you can't expect everyone to have read) answers a question then it should be enough to provide that quote.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Abstractly it's all "documentation". The size of the "documentation" is rather irrelevant. The point is that it *does* exist, and given enough time to read over it all one can find it, but short of that a user here is guiding you to the relevant part(s). It's still of little value in the long run if the answer is literally "Look [here] for X".

Comment: @DrewReese If someone doesn't know something, answer to which lies in the C standard specification that doesn't mean it is a basic question. Minority of developers have read the C standard. So I disagree with  your last comment, but we can agree to disagree I suppose.

Comment: Who said anything about anything being a "basic question"? You are asking about plagiarism and simply completely quoting some external documentation with no other wording of your own, yeah?

Comment: @DrewReese "... if the question is so basic that simply".......It was your comment.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I meant if the form of the question was so basic that simply being pointed to documentation was sufficient to answer it, then it is not a good question.

Comment: @DrewReese I see and that's what I disagreed about. Like with the C standard. It's hundreds of pages and not many people have read it. So if someone asks question answer to which lies in specification, it doesn't make it a bad question IMHO. But that's my opinion, we can disagree on that I suppose.

Comment: A while ago a moderator deleted an answer for exactly this reason [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419330/4284627), and the community strongly disagreed with the deletion and the answer got undeleted.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Thanks for the link the answer there apparently says quote only answers can be ok

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava No, the actions there indicate that it's OK to have an answer which is entirely **quoting yourself**, so is, in fact, your own content and does comply with the policy. That's a *major* difference from quoting something that is *not your own work*. While that answer is *better as a quote*, because it makes it clear that the answer is the official documentation and prevents people from thinking it was plagiarized, that answer isn't actually required to be a quote or provide attribution, because the person who posted the answer is **quoting themselves**.

Comment: @Makyen I am not sure I follow what you said. My point is I agree with this quote by Boltclock from that link: "Granted, there are some situations where indeed there isn't much more to be said than one or two well-written paragraphs from a documentation section or a language specification. That's fine, you're not going to get into trouble for doing that every now and then. Just remember that you still need to provide attribution and quote the text as required above.", and to me it feels current Help centers statement doesn't reflect that, it suggests quote only answers will likely be deleted.

Comment: @Makyen I am not sure what you refer to by quoting yourself? Is that talked about in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419330/why-was-this-answer-deleted-by-a-mod)  link?

Comment: I was, specifically, talking about the link in the immediately preceding 2 comments *and which you added to your question*. That link is about a situation where the author was quoting themselves, because they were quoting documentation *which they wrote*. If you want to reference a particular thing said by Boltclock, then please reference what Boltclock wrote from where they wrote it, not where someone else cherry-picked one paragraph out of 11+ in Boltclock's actual answer and applied it to a substantially different situation (i.e. where someone was quoting themselves).

Comment: And, yes, it was explicitly stated in [this answer](/a/419342/3773011) to that MSO question that the author of the answer that MSO question is asking about is also the author of the documentation which that person was quoting. In other words, that they were quoting themselves. We don't know how the situation would have been resolved if it wasn't a self-quote. Because it was a self-quote, the entire issue of referencing *work by others* was inapplicable. [Again, it's helpful if they indicate the source and that they are the author of the content, but it's not *required*.]

Comment: @Makyen We are talking about quote only answers to any question, for me it absolutely changes nothing whether the quote only answer refers to a self quote, or just link to say documentation. Neither I think Boltclocks quote which I cite would be different depending on a self quote or any quote - because he is mentioning citing documentation or specification. So the Help center could say the prefer it is not a quote only answer, but if it is, it is also ok - and not say that it will be deleted. It is a matter of wording.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava The point is that it is often *not okay* to have a quote only answer. That message would be extremely diluted with the formulations suggested so far. If you think the message should be changed, then I suggest to open a feature-request citing a significant amount of actual examples instead of hypotheticals.

Answer (score 7):

> So this answer while clearly being still useful, would be considered for deletion according to the above quote. Did I get that right?

Yes. The [Stack Overflow standard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) is clear on this:

> Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. In particular, answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.

Consider that it is extremely unlikely that a quote really answers a question by itself *completely*. At the very least, it should be possible to clarify *why* that specific section applies; this may include providing a canonical name for the question subject, or simply pointing out how the specification applies in the specific situation of the question.

In specific, note that the standard says "will **often** be deleted" – for those unlikely cases where a quote actually fits verbatim, moderators have leeway to let such an answer stand. However, this is no excuse for the many, many other situations where a quote by itself is not a verbatim fit.

Comment: Maybe I read the rule strictly but if something like this suffices in answer then it is ok: "Hey yeah this is not the way to use function `f` and here is sentence to back it up". Otherwise I would disagree with this: "Consider that it is extremely unlikely that a quote really answers a question by itself completely"

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava As mentioned, the rule does explicitly not set a strict requirement; feel free to gamble. In my experience, a bare quote is practically *never* a complete answer unless the question specifically asks for just a reference (which comes with its own set of problems). Perhaps providing some actual examples instead of paraphrased situations would be useful? For example, for "Hey yeah this is not the way to use function `f` and here is sentence to back it up" I would expect that the answer should encompass also showing how to actually use `f` in this situation.

Comment: I have yet to see a sequence of characters in English that describe a technical situation that would not be helped by well written commentary

Answer (score 3):

I'm of the opinion the paragraphs referenced in this question should be excised from the Help Centre in their entirety.

If a question can be answered via quoting a source *while providing a reference to said source*, **why bother adulterating that quote with anything further**? Short and sweet and to the point is far preferable to adding noise just to get around an apparently arbitrary imposition.

Further, considering that [apparently **literally anything** can be an answer if you squint hard enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/70345), a quote-only answer should be considered perfectly valid. It's also likely to be far more useful and coherent than some of the other "answers" I've had NAA flags rejected for.

Some members have raised here (in comments and another answer) that the problem is the question itself. However the fact of the matter is that questions that can be answered by quoting a reference have **never** been considered off-topic here, even if said question can be answered by a simple Google search. Stack Overflow wants that SEO juice, after all.

Comment: "Further, considering that apparently literally anything can be an answer if you squint hard enough, a quote-only answer should be considered perfectly valid." I don't think that's enough to say such answers may not be deleted - there are other grounds for deletion than NAA. It's a *requirement* to be an attempted answer, not *sufficient*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Why would you want to delete an answer which is correct? What's wrong if it is just a quote? (maybe with few words added like I mentioned in the example)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Because correctness isn't sufficient. For example if you duplicate an existing answer from SO, it's still correct and it still gets deleted. Personally I see less of an issue with CW answer that are entirely quoted since it looses the aspect of using third-party content for ones own benefit. Still, I see a benefit in having clear rules instead of trying to cover every edge-case and still failing due to them being inherently vague. Remember that Moderators are not expected to be SMEs for the moderated content, so any rule that depends on correctness is flaky.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I would not duplicate SO answer because that could mean it is the same question. So then you can link to the same question. But I don't know. Anyway, my point is that if I give a solution which is attributed and it solves the problem, there should be no need to add something on top of it. btw. not sure what you meant with "CW" answer.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava "CW" means [Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki). Such a post does not give reputation to the author.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi fyi just wanted to show this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419330/why-was-this-answer-deleted-by-a-mod

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava fyi just wanted to quote this: ["Boltclock's position is consistent with the official rules in the help center, which don't at any point say that quote-only answers are outright banned or *must* be deleted."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419346/5349916)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah that is why I shared it with you so it says quote only answers are ok, but statement from Help center doesn't reflect that, at least the way I read it

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava It doesn't say they are okay. It says they *can be* okay. And the help center does so too. "Boltclock's position is **consistent with the official rules in the help center**, which don't at any point say that quote-only answers are outright banned or must be deleted." Which is also what my answer explicitly points out, just in case it's needed to point that out again; or to demonstrate again that a quote by itself is often poor.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi We are having some miscommunication, the Help center currently says essentially quote only answers will be deleted. It says: "...will often be deleted"

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava "the Help center currently says essentially only quoted answers **will be deleted**" It doesn't. It says "...will **often** be deleted" . That extra word is there on purpose.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah well, that "often" is quite suspicious and shouldn't be there imho :)

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava "...shouldn't be there imho" Sorry, I don't follow. Isn't that exactly what you want? That quote-only answers may be valid?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ah I see what you mean now. No, the "often" there suggests that a quote only answer will likely be deleted. At least the way I read it. So I would write it differently.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Yes, it is likely that a quote only answer will be deleted.  Doesn't mean it is always deleted.  It is likely that someone claiming to have overturned physics is a crackpot, doesn't mean everyone who does so is a crackpot.  Just most of them.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont That is exactly the point then the answer above by Ian and my question are trying to make then that such answers should not be deleted. Or help center should reword the statement by saying they prefer it is not a quote only answer, but if it is, that is also ok. Not saying it will be deleted.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava The help center *doesn't say it will be deleted*.  It says it is likely to be deleted.  You keep on saying it will be deleted, or won't be deleted, and that isn't what the help center says.  Either one.  It states it is likely to be deleted.  Which is **true**.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I think you didn't read my comments carefully. That is exactly what I am saying: that they should not be "likely" deleted. Because sometimes it is ok to have quote only answers. So I wouldn't say in that statement that they will "often be deleted". I would just say it is ok to use quote only answers too, although they aren't preferred.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava And I disagree.  99% of quote only answers should be deleted and over 90% will be.  When you ignore **often** repeatedly and replace it with **always** that is on you, not on people reading you.  You: "Not saying it will be deleted." -- will is not *often*, it is *always*.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It is your right to disagree, but here it says they are fine: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/419346/3963067. ps. I didn't replace it with *always*. Rather as it is written now, it suggests they will likely be deleted.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava " that usually an ideal answer to a question will consist of more than just a quote from the docs" -- no, it doesn't say it is usually ok.  It says *rarely* it is ok.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont yes in that link they don't encourage it, but when there are such quote only answers, they say it is ok to have them.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Yes, and yet it remains true that quote-only answers **often** should be deleted.  It is rare that a quote-only answer is correct.  It doesn't say they will be deleted, it doesn't say they shouldn't be deleted, it says they often will be deleted (and implies they should be).  It is giving correct guidance.  It even says how to improve quote-only answers.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Again, the way I read the link I showed you, they don't say we should delete quote only answers. They say if it answers the question it is ok. But they say they don't encourage it. "It is rare that a quote-only answer is correct" --> This statement also feels wrong to me.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava The link agrees that it is rare that a quote-only answer is correct.  I'm not sure what to do when the link you claim is supporting you isn't supporting you, and I quote the very first sentence of the link you provide that shows it isn't supporting you, and you still think the link you provide supports you.  "usually an ideal answer to a question will consist of more than just a quote from the docs" - the rest of the answer proceeds to talk about the **narrow** path an answer can follow such that a quote-only answer is correct.  "strictly speaking", "[not] outright banned", etc.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Does that answer say anywhere that you should delete an existing quote only answer?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava It says that the rules "don't at any point say that quote-only answers […] *must* be deleted". Which still covers that such an answer *can* be deleted.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You cited different thing, you cited part which claims that Boltclocks position is consistent with the Help Center. To me it isn't because Boltclock still doesn't say that such answers should or could be deleted (which help center suggests will happen). But that is not important now. The point is Boltclocks position to my understanding as well as the persons who gave that answer, and mine and also Ian's answer above is: that is if a quote only answer happens to answer the question, there is no need to delete it. But they don't encourage such answers.

Comment: ps. By quote only answers I mean answers which are mostly quote. You can of course add a sentence like "hey this is not how `f` should be used and here is quote from docs which shows that"

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava We're going in circles here. Fact is, the help center does not *require* deletion of quote-only answers – *no one is denying this here*. However, whether "a quote only answer happens to answer the question" is not something a moderator is expected to judge, since moderators are assumed not to be subject matter experts. As a result any such rule, be it written in the help center or on meta, cannot be a binding one.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yeah I also feel I have to repeat myself several times. I think we can wrap up slowly. I said I think Boltclock's position in that link was that: Quote only answers are ok if they answer the question, but they aren't encouraged. I have same position. Now whether moderators can't evaluate that, that is a separate thing. For that matter I would not word the Help center statement like that and would have said, that "We don't encourage quote only answers, but sometimes they can be ok". And I would not mention deleting them.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava "Not must" means in standard English "sometimes". It nowhere states that "deleting is bad". It supports the help guidelines, which state they are usually deleted. Your link in no way supports your position that quote-only answers should usually left undeleted. It supports the position that, in a certain narrow set of circumstances, quote-only answers are ok. Which is not the same as they shouldn't usually be deleted. You might not want bad answers to be deleted, but most quote only answers are *bad*, and should be deleted. Some, in narrow situations, are not.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am mainly referring to quote by Boltclock in that link. To me it says:  In some rare cases when quote only answer happens to answer the question, it is ok to give such answers; and they will not be deleted. But again such answers are not encouraged. It seems you are reading it differently, then show me where is Boltclock suggesting to delete such answers. Otherwise we can wrap it up I guess, because it seems we are going in circles as other user noted.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I cannot tell what you mean by "such answers".  I could read your post as having two or more completely different positions based on what your phrase "such answers" refers to.  Is "such answers" all "quote only answers", or is it the rare case of "quote only answers that happens to fully answer the question well"?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Could you elaborate how you read my post with different positions? I am simply curious. By quote only answers I was always referring to answers which fully answer the question.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava By yes, I mean exactly what I'm thinking, which is by definition clear.  By definition, I mean what I want.  I understand you have some kind of replacement of words similar to the "no true scotsman", where you mean the words you say insofar as you redefine them to mean what you want them to mean?  /shrug.  "quote only answers" are answers which contain nothing but a quote.  Very few of them are valid.  If you define "quote only answers" as "answers that shouldn't be deleted", then ... they shouldn't be deleted.  But that isn't how anyone else will read your words.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I didn't define quote only answers as answers which shouldn't be deleted, I assumed them as quote only answers *which answer the question*, because it doesn't make sense to talk about answers which don't answer the question (be they quote only or not). And then I suggested that  such answers don't be deleted. Then I simply asked out of curiosity what did you mean with interpreting my post with different positions, you replied: "By yes, I mean exactly what I'm thinking, which is by definition clear. By definition, I mean what I want." - what were you trying to say here?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Ok, do you include in "answers the question" answers that, with a PhD in the subject area and you squint at sideways, provide a tiny amount of information which could generously be interpreted as a hint asto the actual answer, but confirming that is NP-hard?  Or "answers the question", does it mean "provides a complete solution to the OPs concerns in both clear and simple english and is technically correct and authoritative"?  As to your quote of me, I was being completely clear, by definition.

Comment: The only reasonable definition for "quote only answers" that applies here is "text in the answer field of the stack overflow Q&A format that consists entirely, or almost entirely, of a quote".  If you define it as something different (without being clear each and every time you do so), then your attempt at communication will fail.  If you want your attempt at communication to fail, continue to define it to be something else, and be as shocked as you want to be when nobody else understands you.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am not sure I follow what point you are trying to make with the part abut Phd and squints etc. To your question I meant the second: "provides a complete solution to the OPs concerns in both clear and simple English and is technically correct and authoritative".

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The reason I asked you to clarify what you meant with reading my comment with different positions was because in my comment to which you referred to I had already said “In some rare cases when quote only answer happens to answer the question, it is ok to give such answers” – which means it is only ok to give such answers when they answer the question. Isn't it? So why did you read it differently?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Also I am not sure what is meant: "As to your quote of me, I was being completely clear, by definition.". How can you be clear by definition? Being clear is about communication. Also look at the original question, it talks about quote only answer to which *there is nothing to add or remove* doesn't that suggest it is the kind of answer which answers the question?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Keep in mind that a "quote only answer to which there is *nothing* to add or remove" is indistinguishable from a "quote only answer to which there is *something* to add or remove" without (extensive) subject matter expertise or even just by subjective impression. When defining a rule for one that automatically means defining a rule for the other. So when you propose changes to the rules about "quote only answers" it is really not clear that you mean one and not the other.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Let me say once again. Yeah I was referring to quote only answers that answer the question initially. I didn't refer to those that don't answer the question. But if a quote only answer doesn't answer the question, then it isn't an answer in the first place right? Doesn't matter if it is quote only or not. So what is the policy for incorrect answers on SO? Do they get deleted? If answer is incorrect, it has nothing to do with if it is quote only or not, and in that case regular SO rules for incorrect answers should apply, isn't it?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava As far as SO is concerned, an answer is everything that is written into the answer box. There is a thin line for NAA ("Not An Answer" flag) if the content is incapable of answering any on-topic question, e.g. an answer that is just Lorem Ipsum. There are no specific rules for *incorrect* answers because it is hard to objectively define what that is.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's the point if there is not rule for incorrect answers, why is there delete rule for incorrect quote only answers? (Btw. I am not defending incorrect quote only answers, like I said I always referred to the ones which answer the question).

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava "why is there delete rule for incorrect quote only answers" There isn't. Moderators have leeway not to delete quote only answers. The rules don't say when to apply that, and especially don't refer to anything as vague as correctness.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's the problem, the way it is currently written suggests most of the quote only answers (including the ones which answer the question) will be deleted, and that's exactly the reason why I posted my initial question. That many quote only answers answer the question and shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava "That many quote only answers answer the question and shouldn't be deleted." As mentioned, it would really help to have some concrete evidence or at least examples for this. Otherwise there really isn't anything else to say.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi you mean like a real world example of an answer?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Yes. Ideally, more than one to back up the point that *many* quote-only-answers-answering-the-question-perfectly get deleted.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I don't have such ones especially the ones which *were deleted*. But I asked this because someone could in the future. I had my own answer which had like 70 votes and was mostly a quote from the docs. I rewrote it due to this rule actually :). I can imagine other answers which can be quotes. Take specification of some language. Someone might throw a quote from there which could answer a question.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Then I recommend to bring up this issue again when the future comes and you don't have to imagine such answers but can actually cite them. The SO rules are heuristics, they don't work perfectly, but neutering them for a hypothetical issue seems very far fetched.

Comment: Most quote only answers are not good answers to the question.  If you define "quote only answer" as "answer that is a good answer to the question", you are not communicating effectively.  If you don't correct this error when it is pointed out, you are willfully not communicating clearly.  If you include "utterly horrible things that are not NAA, but at least vaguely related to the question and are in the form of an answer, and are quote only" as "answers the question", you are also not communicating clearly, but excluding ... I don't know what, something? ... then please stop.

Comment: I am uninterested in a discussion in which "quote only answers" are somehow restricted by definition to some specific subset (defined in your mind) of things people put in the "answer" section of stack overflow and consist almost entirely of a quote.  That is using semantics to argue, not to communicate.  Most quote only answers should be deleted.  That is what the guidelines say, and they are (in my experience) correct.  Your internal subset of "quote only answers" is something that exists in your brain, and I do not know what it is, nor do I really care, and nor should anyone else.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Incorrect quote only answers which don't answer the question are incorrect answers in general right, if incorrect answers don't get deleted on SO, why should the incorrect quote only answers be deleted? Yes I assumed only correct quote only answers in my question (see the original quote "isn't really anything to add or remove"), maybe because I thought the incorrect quote only answers would be treated same as other incorrect answers on SO, and they didn't need special attention.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I am glad you have learned something here today.  I hope you now take that understanding into the world.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont What did I learn, can you be more specific? In my previous comment I explained, why I could have ignored the incomplete quote only answers, isn't it?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Neither the statement from Help Center makes you think that most of those quote only answers which will be deleted will be deleted because they are wrong. The way it is written suggests, whether the answer was wrong or correct, won't play a role in deciding whether to delete it or not (see their quote "do not contain any original content"). That's why maybe I thought correctness had nothing to do with this rule, and didn't highlight in my question, and assumed correct quote only answers.